# Появление блока на определенный период jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы по клику на элемент, появлялся другой элемент с анимацией появления и через 5 секунд так же пропадал.

По отдельности я знаю как сделать появление и скрывание элемента с анимацией, но как задействовать settimeout - не знаю.

Вот пример кода:

```css
.box-size {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="box-size">
<a class="click-btn">Нажать</a>
</div>
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
</form>

<script>
$(".click-btn").click(function() {
$('.button').appendTo(this);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопку изначально делать невидимой, при клике показывать и ставить таймаут на 2 сек на скрытие.

```js
$(".click-btn").click(function() {
  $('.button').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.button').hide();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.box-size {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="box-size">
    <a class="click-btn">Нажать</a>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
</form>
```